# How to get data from task queues?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, task-queue

How to get data from task queues ?? 
How to pull queues ??
My project is running using google App Engine.
I insert or push data at task queue successfully , now I want to pull those data.
I need PHP code for this work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you are using a *Push Queue* or a *Pull Queue*, but I assume you are trying to *lease* (not 'pull') tasks from the queue.

If you are trying to use a Pull Queue, according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/):

> **Warning**: There is currently no support for pull queues in the PHP runtime for Google App Engine.

If you are trying to lease tasks from a Push Queue, you simply need to implement a regular handler that is **determined by the path part of the URL (the forward-slash separated string following the hostname), which is specified as the first argument (the url_path) of the PushTask constructor.**

The task parameters that you supply when you enqueue the Task will be available as regular POST data.

Overview docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push#PHP_Task_execution